# LibreOffice Impress, Can't Get Rounded Corners

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I can't find the setting to make rounded corners. I have clicked everything that says "rounded".  No effect.

What do I do to get a box like this original author has ?

**ALT-H, ABOUT, ETC....**

- Version: 4.4.5.2
- Build ID: a22f674fd25a3b6f45bdebf25400ed2adff0ff99
- Locale: en_US

[image: The rounded edges that I'm see from the other guy]

[image: The sharp edges which I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I can't find the setting to make rounded corners.

> Using Customize Toolbar, you can add the Rectangles toolbar.
>
> **Rounded Rectangle**
>
> [image] Draws a rounded rectangle with a fill where you drag in the current document. Click where you want to place a corner of the rounded rectangle, and drag to the size you want. To draw a rounded square, hold down Shift while you drag.
>
> **Rounded Square**
>
> [image] Draws a rounded square with a fill where you drag in the current document. Click where you want to place a corner of the rounded square, and drag to the size you want. To draw a rounded rectangle, hold down Shift while you drag.

Source [Rectangles](https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Rectangles)

---

> When you insert a rectangle or a callout box using the drawing functions and activate the Points icon on the Drawing toolbar, you see a small frame at the upper left corner of the object.
>
> The frame indicates the amount by which the corners are rounded. When the frame is positioned at the top left corner, no rounding occurs.
>
> When the frame is positioned on the handle centered at the top of the object, the corners are rounded as much as possible.
>
> You adjust the degree of rounding by moving the frame between these two positions.
>
> If you place the cursor on the box it changes to a hand symbol [image]. You can now drag the box to change the amount of rounding. An outline shows a preview of the result.

Source [Creating Round Corners](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Creating_Round_Corners)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Text Box
2. Menu: Format->Object and Shape->Postition and Size->Slant & Corner Radius tab (Shortcut <kbd>F4</kbd>)

[image: A text box with rounded corners and the settings dialog]

Comment: Can you expand this to include some screenshots?